# 'how to instruction' using javascript/jquery for first signed up users

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can anyone please tell me some tips to create a 'how to use this website' instruction using javascript/jquery for those first signed up users (like the ones you see when you first sign up for facebook or twitter)? And my website is based on php/mysql. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: That's a wide question. Tell us what you've tried

Comment: Think about your question, edit it, and ask it properly; it doesn't seem clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by

first create a table with the field you want to show for first time user

than make design for that and on loading the page change the status in table 0 to 1 so next time when user load the page he wont get same

check ever time when user load that if 0 than show the instruction